# Missing name after . operator YUI Compressor for socket.io js files

Tags: javascript, socket.io, yui, minify

I am trying to use YUI compressor for socket.io based .js file (yes, I know it's server side script and doesn't require minfication, but it's requirement so I have a less control). My code is like this:

```
fs.readFile('../examples/example.xml', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // parsing the new xml data and converting them into json file
  var json = parser.toJson(data);
  // adding the time of the last update
  json.time = new Date();
  // send the new data to the client
  socket.volatile.emit('notification', json);
});
```

When I execute YUI compressor I get error @ this line:

```
socket.volatile.emit('notification', json);

[ERROR] 36:22:missing name after . operator
```

I assume it is throwing error becase volatile is keyword right? Can anyone guide me how to get rid of this error.

Comment: socket['volatile'].emit()

Comment: @user32225 wow!! that's great. If you post it as an answer, I can upvote and accept it :)

Comment: Thaks for the tip, I'll do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

no compressor will mess with reserved words if enclosed in quotes

```
socket['volatile'].emit()
```

Comment: works great, solved my similar problem with a '.super' property